# android - finish() closes app instead of the activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, activity-finish

I'm a begginer android programmer, and I seem to have a problem:
I open new activitys, with

```
Intent newGameIntent = new Intent(actionName);
startActivity(newGameIntent);
```

and everythings works fine, the activity opens.
but when i call finish() it doesnt goes to the previus activity, it just closes the app(no errors or other log messeges)

does anyone have an idea why is it happening?
Thanks for your time!

by request, here is more of the code(of the stuff that i might have totally screwd up):
first activity:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop(); 
    SplashScreen.sounds.releasSounds();
    finish();
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    pauseActivity();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    gameLoop.resumeThread();
    SplashScreen.sounds.resumeSounds();
}

private void pauseActivity() {
    gameLoop.pauseThread();
    SplashScreen.sounds.pauseBck();
}
```

and the first activity calling the seconds activity

```
Intent newGameIntent = new Intent("com.YuvalApps.menus.NEWGAMEMENU");
    startActivity(newGameIntent);
```

and for the seconds activity

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();

}
```

Comment: is there any other activity in the stack ??

Comment: what do you mean? is it possible the new activity overwrites the previus one?

Comment: You should take a look at this : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: Do you have this attribute `android:noHistory` set in your `Activities`

Comment: slickelito thanks ill take a look and siddiharth: no, i dont

Comment: everytime you start an activity, the activity is add in the activity stack and is not removed until it is destroyed, either by traversing back the entire stack or if the system does not have enough resources, or by explicitly calling finish. If you call finish on an activity which is the sole activity in the stack then, the previous task is visible, in your case the homescreen.

Comment: thanks, but that is not what is happening, i start a new activity with startActivity, and when i finish the second activity the app closes instead of returning to the first activity

Comment: finish will not cause any problem. make sure your 1st activity is not finished.

Comment: im sure, thats what confusing me, havnt closed it anywhere in the code... even when i go to a third activity and finish it (even from startActivityForResult()) it still closes the entire app

Comment: how many finish() calls are there in your app?

Comment: Thank you @IceMAN. This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When one activity was in background, The android system will invoke "onStop" method, But you invoke the method "finish" in method "onStop", So if you jump to another activity, the previous activity will destroyed by "onStop".
  You should remove "finish" in "onStop" method.

Comment: wow, thank you so much! cant belive i was that stupid. guess i dont fully understand the activity life cycle yet

Answer (score -1):

If you are calling finish() to close the current activity and go back to the previous one, just call onBackPressed() instead of finish().It will take you back to the previous activity.

Comment: if you see the source code, you'll find, onBackPressed simply calls finish(). It makes sense -> Poping an item from the activity stack

Comment: still closes the app... i dont think finish() was my problem, because when im in my 2nd activity, (without closing my first one, just opening a second) and i press the back button it closes the app and doesnt return to the 1st activity

Comment: Can you add code of any of the activity so that we can find the error?